# Java API for Report writer

Tags: java, reporting

I want to integrate a report writer in our web application. Right now , we have some fixed reports but I want customers to use data in system freely with their own custom reports. I have searched for this using google , I get tons of answers. If some of you who have used any Java API for this, can answer, that will be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Jasper Reports](http://jasperforge.org/plugins/project/project_home.php?projectname=jasperreports) is one of the best known.  Or maybe [Windward Reports](http://www.windwardreports.com/java.htm?source=javareports&id=117) is more of what you had in mind.

Comment: Have you used Jasper reports for web application? I want to integrate jasper reports in my web application, so end business users can create any report they want. These users are not technical users.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend **[i-net Clear Reports](http://www.inetsoftware.de/products/crystal-clear)** (used to be called i-net Crystal-Clear) sporting an ad-hoc reporting component that is made to be an easy-to-use thing for non-technical users. Your users won't have to know anything about reporting at all. They simply select the kind of report, the data et voila there is a report suiting the needs.

The product is embeddable into existing web applications and even supports web-skins so your users / customers won't recognise it's actually "third party". ;)

i-net Clear Reports is entirely Java and offers a large API for doing all kinds of stuff with reports as well (creating, modifying …).

Disclosure: Yep. I work for the company who built this.